# Override CiviCRM settings

Tags: settings

I want to override my CiviCRM settings. I am new with CiviCRM and I don't know where to put the line referenced in the attached image. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is the question where to find your `civicrm.settings.php` file?  If so, please edit the question to include which CMS you're using (WordPress, Drupal, Backdrop, Joomla)

Comment: I am using Drupal. I know where to find the civicrm.settings.php. My concern is everytime I add those line in civicrm.settings.php, I am always got an error about path.

Comment: Whenever I add those lines inside the civicrm.settings.php. I always getting this kind or error. "Failed to make directory (customFileUploadDir) at /var/www/testing/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload. Please update the settings or file permission"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to update the directory "/var/www/testing/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload" to reflect your installation directory:

```
/var/www/yoursitefoldernamehere/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload
```

There may be another subfolder in your setup, like htdocs before the 'sites' folder as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this in civicrm.settings.php. Once you have added overided the settings clear CiviCRM cache so that the settings are updated correctly.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Whenever I add those lines inside the civicrm.settings.php. I always getting this kind or error. "Failed to make directory (customFileUploadDir) at /var/www/testing/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload. Please update the settings or file permission"

Comment: isn't this an issue with your server settings w.r.t. the permissions on that file. basically it is saying ' you don't have permission to edit/save this file'

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be an issue with your server settings w.r.t. the permissions on that file. basically it is saying 'you don't have permission to edit/save this file' so you either needs to fix them or use sudo